# Difficulty in obtaining the density of y

Tags: joint-distribution, conditional-expectation

[image]

I know how to obtain expectation of conditional distribution. We first need to obtain the conditional distribution of X given Y. Then, divide this by the individual PDF of Y. But, in this particular problem, I am not sure how can I obtain the PDF of Y. Here, the region is to the right of Y-axis but I am not sure of the limits of integration while calculating the PDF of Y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set y to -1 ,as x is greater than mod y,to get the probability of y=-1, just integrate f over all x keeping y as -1.
So basically integrate f for x=1 to infinity

Comment: This should have had the self-study tag and therefore hints should have been given rather than a complete answer.